# CSS How can I make button show image

Tags: css

I have a question about making a button show image
For example, I have four buttons
I want Each button showing image in the same content for images

In other words:
When you press one of the buttons show you image

here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/i5yal/yvCtQ/1/

```
<div id="section-container">
<div class="section-img-container"><a>images will appear here</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="section-button-container"><div>
<div class="section-button1"><a>1</a>
</div>

<div class="section-button2"><a>2</a>
</div>

<div class="section-button3"><a>3</a>
</div>

<div class="section-button4"><a>4</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
    #section-container {
background-color: #C0C0C0;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#section-button-container {
width: 300px;
height: 30px;
margin:0 auto;
}

.section-button1 {
background-color: #808000;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
float: left;
display: block;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.section-button2 {
background-color: #808000;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
float: left;
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.section-button3 {
background-color: #808000;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
float: left;
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.section-button4 {
background-color: #808000;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
float: left;
display: block;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
}

.section-img-container {
background-color: #008080;
background-position: center center;
width: 270px;
height: 270px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: For accessibility why not do `<input type="image" src="..." alt="Section 1"/>`

Comment: There are several ways to do this. if you want the image to be clickable (seems u do I see an anchor tag there) then you can have a default image with say a question mark or something in your anchor then just change its source with jquery. if that is what ur looking for comment and I'll post an example for you.

Comment: @C.Hazelton +  Ryan B 
Thank you for your answer,
To be clear my question I want to do Something like this:
http://tympanus.net/Development/BookBlock/index2.html

Comment: I see I take it u like the plugin but doesn't give you the layout or look u want? All that is happening there (disclaimer: going off exp didn't dig into plugin) is the source of the anchor as I mentioned is getting changes that is really simple. As to the "flipping" that is prob a css3 transformation or it should be for best performance on mobile platforms. Are we in the correct direction?

Comment: @C.Hazelton No I do not want flipping I use Opera browser It does not Supports flipping, if you saw the white buttons and the green button If you press the button shows you another picture
This is what I want to do, to make every button show another picture

Comment: You have to viable responses. Either Dave's css example should work fine for you or mine using script. If u need more control use script, if just simple need go with the css.

Comment: thanks @C.Hazelton 
I'm going to try Dave's css example
I do not have a great knowledge of Java Script, etc.
I want to do it simple with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid using JavaScript, it's possible to use CSS (albeit there has to be some minor adjustments to your HTML in order to do so); so given the amended HTML:

```
<div id="section-container">
    <div class="section-img-container">
        <input type="radio" name="images" id="img1" />
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300/" />
        <input type="radio" name="images" id="img2" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nightlife" />
        <input type="radio" name="images" id="img3" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" />
        <input type="radio" name="images" id="img4" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/f90.png&text=image+lorem+ipsum" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="section-button-container"><div>
    <div class="section-button1">
        <label for="img1">1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="section-button2">
        <label for="img2">2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="section-button3">
        <label for="img3">3</label>
    </div>

    <div class="section-button4">
        <label for="img4">4</label>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#section-button-container label {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=radio],
input[type=radio] + img {
    display: none;
}

input:checked + img {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yvCtQ/2/).

This does require that the browser supports the `:checked` pseudo-selector and the CSS next-sibling `+` combinator, however; and takes advantage of the `label` being able to check/uncheck a radio input (so long as the `for` attribute of the `label` identifies the `id` of the relevant `input`).

References:

- [`:checked` pseudo-selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked).
- [`:checked` pseudo-selector compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t60).

Answer (score 0):

For the animation portion investigate this library, used it myself and it works nicely => [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/)

for the changing of the image it is rather trivial here is one way to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var viewer = $('img.viewer');
    $('a.section-button').click(function () {
        viewer.attr('src', 'your new path to new image');
    });
});
```

In the above I added the classes that would be attached to the main view area so you'd have:

```
  <img class="veiwer" />.
```

You'd just hide this or load up a default image when the page loads.

Also using "section-button" class on each anchor. I didn't account for positioning in the list of choices there meaning 1, 2, 3, 4th picture and so on. It might be easiest to have data-attributes for that on the section buttons. So something like.

```
<a class="section-button" data-imgrc="path to the large image" data-number="1">1</a>
```

Note you could also if you just have numbers inside the section buttons just grabber the inner text however personally I prefer data-attributes.

Comment: Thank you
I'm going to try this way

Thank you very much

Comment: please vote as answered either mine or Dave's the both work. Watching stack all day so post back if you get stuck.

Comment: thanks @C.Hazelton ,
I hope that i do not stuck.. :P
But really thank you for your help